# How can I set key bindings for show and hide Sublime Text line numbers?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to build a new key binding on Sublime Text to show or hide the line numbers.

Do somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting used to show or hide line numbers is `line_numbers`. For instance, setting `line_numbers: false` in your User preferences file would permanently hide line numbers.

Now to answer your question, to toggle a setting, you can add the following to your User keybindings file:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+l"],
    "command": "toggle_setting",
    "args":
    {
        "setting": "line_numbers"
    }
}
```

You can change <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to whatever keys you want.

If you ever want to toggle any other setting in the future, you can just use this exact code, but you would just have to change the `"line_numbers"` to the name of the setting you want to toggle.